# Is there any way to filter out some data in copy activity when source is Blob storage and sink is SQL database?

Tags: azure, etl, azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Azure blobs to azure SQL database using Azure Data Factory.

The azure blobs are incrementally stored everytime in the storage account. They are just JSON having key-value pairs. So I want to filter the data on the basis of one key-value before it get copied inside the SQL databse.

Answer (score 0):

you could use stored procedure to do some filtering before writing into your db.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think stored procedure would work only when the source is sql database, when it is blob storage then the data need to be in sql database form and then invoke a stored procedure to filter out, which would be the same cost. So do you know some possible way to achieve direct copy from blob to SQL with filtering on Blobs which are in JSON (on the basis of a key value pair) so that the cost of writing the data could be deducted.